# R - curl Github API to access private repos

Tags: r, curl

All I'm trying to do is read all the repos and issues in my organizations private repos.  I can from my Windows 7 `cmd.exe` execute

```
curl -u "user:pass" https://api.github.com/orgs/:org/repos
```

and I get back all of my repositories.  I can pipe this to a file:

```
curl -u "user:pass" https://api.github.com/orgs/:org/repos > "C:\Users\Location\file.txt"
```

and this saves the JSON output.  I can replicate this in R but in what seems like a terrible way.

```
fullRepos = system('curl -s -u "user:pass" -G https://api.github.com/orgs/:org/repos',
                   intern=T,show.output.on.console = F)
```

This captures the output (`intern = T`) and the `-s` gets rid of the progress bars so I can collapse the lines and turn it into a data frame.  This gets back all the repositories, public and private.

I tried using `RCurl` to do the same thing but the code below only provides the public repositories.  The `httpheader` is because otherwise it the API rejects my call.

```
RCurl::getURL(url="https://api.github.com/orgs/:org/repos",userpwd ="user:pass",
              httpheader = c('User-Agent' = "A user agent"))
```

I also tried `httr` and it also only provides the public repositories.

```
httr::GET(url="https://api.github.com/orgs/:org/repos",userpwd="user:pass")
```

What am I doing wrong with `RCurl` and `httr`?  I'd rather have a workflow that doesn't make a system command and then paste the lines together.

Comment: There are (IIRC) 3 github-API packages for R. Why aren't you using them?

Comment: I believe they are all based on OAuth which doesn't give access to private repositories.  At least, I can't figure out how to get my application to request access to private repositories.  Regardless of the Github specific nature here though, I'm also interested in why I can't replicate the `curl` call in `RCurl` or `httr`.

Comment: try `httr::GET(url="https://api.github.com/orgs/:org/repos", httr::authenticate("user", "pass"), httr::verbose())`

Comment: @hrbrmstr That works! Would you post it as an answer that I can accept?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use the `authenticate()` helper function in `httr` to build the authentication header for us w/o having to manually create it. Also, `verbose()` can be used to debug HTTP issues:

```
httr::GET(url="https://api.github.com/orgs/:‌​org/repos",
          httr::authenticate("user", "pass"), 
          httr::verbose())
```

Comment: Just in case this one catches anybody off-guard, this works, but will only return first page of repos... to get second page, need to add `?page=2`. Also, to actually view the content, you'll have to pass through `content(x)`